# About continuity in the derivative of a function at relative extremum points

Tags: calculus

Is there a counter example that rejects the continuity of the derivative of a function at the relative extremum points? The meaning is to assume that the function in the open interval l is the derivative of a point c is the relative extremum in this interval, in this case the derivative of this point will be zero, but is the limit  The derivative function will be zero when x tends to c?

Comment: $x^2(2+\sin(1/x))$